# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable error sending text to Email field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Set-up**

Trying to log into [this log-in form](https://activeshop.com.pl/customer/account/login/) using Python and Selenium.

---

**Code**

```
url = 'https://activeshop.com.pl/customer/account/login/'
browser.get(url)


# fill out login details 
account_name = 'my@email.com' 
password = 'mypassword' 

login_details = {
                'login': account_name,
                'password': password
                }

# inserts account name in login field      
fill_field('id','email',login_details['login'])      

# inserts password in password field
fill_field('id','pass',login_details['password'])
```

where,

```
def fill_field(type, type_path, input):
    if type == 'id':
        field = browser.find_element_by_id(type_path)        
    field.clear()
    field.send_keys(input)
```

---

**Issue**

The above code used to work, but since the site has received a makeover it yields a `ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable` when trying to fill the fields.

I've tried `Xpaths`, `CSS` selectors and whatnot, but the email address and password aren't filled out.

I can obtain texts on the page via Selenium.

There's something blocking Selenium at the `input` elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're more than 1 `email` on the page and first one is not visible. You can get all elements and then filter for visible one:

```
field = list(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), browser.find_elements(By.ID, "email")))[0]
field.send_keys("email")
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence to the **E-mail** and **Hasło** field you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://activeshop.com.pl/customer/account/login/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='E-mail']//following::input[@class='input-text' and @id='email']"))).send_keys("my@email.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hasło']//following::input[@class='input-text' and @title='Hasło']").send_keys("mypassword")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: activeshop_com]